# making a block filling the full width of its container

Tags: css

**How can I make a block filling the full width of its container given the fact both are absolutely positionned, and the inside one has padding.**

I've made a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dmdBB/

here a sample:

```
<style>
.containerOut {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: thin solid black;
}

.containerIn {
    position: absolute;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    width: auto;

    padding: 4px;
}
</style>
<div class="containerOut">
       <div class="containerIn">
          im not large enough
       </div>
</div>
```

In this sample, the .containerIn element is too thin. If I set its width to 100%, it would overflow because of its padding.

PS: I would like a CSS solution, I know that placing an intermediate HTML container with 100%width and 0margin/padding/border would solve the problem.

Comment: @thirtydot that was on purpose, but I can't garantee that my inside block will have contents with sufficent width to make this happen.
Obviously I can put some filler hidden but but and I was interested to know if there was clean css solutions before I make dirty code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `width: 100%`, you need to use `left: 0; right: 0`.

To fix the last example, you can use `word-wrap: break-word`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/QjdD5/1/

```
.containerIn {
    width: auto !important; /*just to override your inline CSS */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

Comment: ah! width auto.. how did i miss that :P

Answer (score 2):

```
right:0px;
left:0px;
overflow:hidden;
```

for the inner element and if you dont want that red border showing on the black border you can use overlfow:hidden for outer div

Answer (score 2):

@biab; padding & border add width to an element.
may  be you can put in your css:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/dmdBB/28/

Comment: I tested that and it seems a good solution but unfortunaltely it broke with my example 4. Anyway you've earn a +1.

Comment: +1, this is also a valid solution. You can fix "example 4" with `word-wrap: break-word`. I'd argue that `left: 0; right: 0` is slightly better in this case because it works in IE7, whereas  `box-sizing` won't.

Answer (score 1):

replace...

width: auto;

with...

left:0;
 right:0;

Tested on chrome

Comment: that still leaves the padding! and the last example.. a overflow hidden for both of them will do the trick..

Comment: @Achshar: Thanks for pointing that out (I'd written much the same answer). I've updated my answer with a fix.

Comment: are you adding the padding? [rhyme, LOL]

Comment: I removed the inline style="width: 100%" from the one case since that seemed irrelevant for the true answer.  I +1 the break-word solution since that helped with the overflow content.